# How to properly set up CALayer hierarchy?

Tags: cocoa, calayer

I'm trying to arrange views one above another, so that front view would appear with some animation. It looks like the only way to achieve that is to use CALayer. Here is code that I use

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  CALayer *frontLayer = [CALayer layer];
  CALayer *rearLayer=[CALayer layer];
  frontLayer.backgroundColor=CGColorCreateGenericRGB( 0.25, 0.45, 0.35, 1.0 );
  frontLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,311, 266,21);

  [_outputText setLayer:rearLayer];
  [_outputText setWantsLayer:YES];

  [_outPutTextHideBox setLayer:frontLayer];
  [rearLayer addSublayer:frontLayer];
}
```

Here `_outputText` is NSTextView and `_outPutTextHideBox` is NSBox.
The problem is that my frontLayer is not displayed on the top of rearLayer. Actually, frontLayer is displayed under rearLayer.

Comment: What do you mean by "the only way to achieve this is to use CALayer"?

Comment: @Justin I did not put it quite correctly. The point is that I want `_outputTextHideBox` to popup with animation and fully overlap `_outputText`. As far as I know, the animation handling is possible only with the help of CALayer. And so I think that to work with animation firstly I need to assign views to layers correctly.